# Disqus comments lost when I changed my site from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: disqus

I have a Jekyll site, and comments have been working fine for years. GitHub dragged their feet on HTTPS support for vanity domains so I gave up waiting and flipped to Netlify and that migration was easy (as was the LetsEncrypt usage).

However, the Disqus comments have disappeared. I saw some advice on how to fix that in [here](https://woorkup.com/migrate-disqus-comments-https/) but the admin interface for Disqus does not have the option that blog entry shows anymore :-(

Yes, I similarly registered the HTTP to HTTPS change in my Disqus settings.

How do I get comments back?

Answer (score 0):

Well I could not work out how to repair my Disqus records and get it working on my blog again, so I went ahead and left Disqus:  https://github.com/paul-hammant/escape_from_disqus (A python script to process your exported Disqus XML dump, and make JSON/HTML snippets)

Answer (score 0):

For everybody having problems after changing the domains for your site that is using [Disqus](https://disqus.com/), the Disqus has a migration tool to be used to solve this kind of problem.

To solve the *https/http* or new domain problem, we can use the tool **Domain Migration**.

Another scenarios when you might use this are:

- You change your domain. Example: You change your web address from www.old-url.com to new-awesome-url.com
- You change your CMS/blogging system and, as a result, the article URL structure is no longer the same. Example: You move from Blogger to Wordpress.
- Two different discussions need to be merged into one.

#### Where to find these tools

Go to your [Disqus](https://disqus.com/admin/moderate/#/approved) Admin and click **Tools** > **Migration Tools** (towards the bottom of the navigation panel on the left).

[image]

#### Migration options available

[image]

- [Domain Migration Wizard](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/912627-domain-migration-wizard) - If the base domain of your website has recently changed, you'll need to migrate the URLs of your commenting threads to use the new base domain (ex: www.old-url.com -> new-awesome-url.com).
- [URL Mapper](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/912757-url-mapper) - If the URL slug of your site's posts has recently changed, you'll need to use our URL Mapper to migrate your commenting threads from the old URL to the new one (ex: yourdomain.com/p=23 -> yourdomain.com/new-page-slug).
- [Redirect Crawler](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/912834-redirect-crawler) - If you've already set up 301 redirects for your site's pages, then use our Redirect Crawler to crawl your site's pages and migrate the URLs of your commenting threads automatically. Recommended for advanced users only.